Chart js beforeTitle in tooltip
I am trying to display custom text before title in tooltip.    This should work according to documentation:  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback
But it only show number.


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [11, 22, 33],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {

        beforeTitle: function(context) {
          return 'before title';

        },

      }
    }
  }
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>




You're missing the plugins object. It should be options: {plugins: {tooltip: {callbacks: {....

Its because you missed the plugins section and you added an s in tooltip.
Change this
options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {

        beforeTitle: function(context) {
          return 'before title';

        },

      }
    }
  }

to this:
options: {
    plugins:{
        tooltip: {
        callbacks: {

          beforeTitle: function(context) {
            return 'before title';

          },
        }
      }
    }
  }

Here is the JSFiddle Demo

Can I put it in the same line as title?

@Toniq Then why not just use the title itself like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yvgcsd0x/1/
